# How to remove common records found in 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example:

```
table 1
        x   y
        2   3
        1   2
        8   9

table 2
        x   y
        2   3
        8   9
```

So here I need to remove the common field found in both the table
result should be

```
Result
      x   y
      1   2
```

only i should get a unique row

Comment: You say remove but your result could be interpreted as a select where you get a unique row from either table or it could be interpreted as meaning delete the non unique rows from both tables. Which is it?

Comment: Do you want **(1)** to select rows from table1 that are not in table2? **(2)** or to select rows that only exist in one of the tables? **(3)** or delete rows from table1 that don't exist in table2? **(4)** or delete rows from both tables that don't exist in the other table? **(5)** or something else still?

Comment: What if we had row '4 , 5' in table 2?

Comment: @Jeevitha, please select and mark correct answer. P.S. You can also give your vote to any answwer that was useful to you...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.X = t1.X AND t2.Y = t1.Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use NOT EXISTS operator which is more efficient as it also considers NULL values while comparison.

```
select * from table1 A
where not exists (select name from table2 B where A.name=B.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**[Demo 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=9ce2a6af8e92d76f919680c04bd1a974)**
**[Demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=3a092cb4696246433a7be2ca1efaf5a1)**

```
select x, y
from
(
  select x, y
  from table1
   union all
  select x, y
  from table2
) i
group by x, y
having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: You should never use a group by without aggregate functions

Comment: Can you please explain why? I am not selecting any field which is not in the `group by` clause.

Comment: Please refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @P.Salmon Aggregate function is used - in HAVING clause.

Comment: @P.Salmon the linked article doesn't say that *never use a group by without aggregate functions*, it says don't `select` columns without aggregate functions if they are not included in the `group by`.

Comment: @Akina thanks, but even without the `having` clause, the query is perfectly valid, across every DBMS.

Comment: *even without the having clause, the query is perfectly valid, across every DBMS* I wouldn't speak for EVERY - maybe there exists some exotic DBMS which does not allow... 'most of DBMSs' or 'every popular DBMS' is more accurate.

Comment: Yep, this looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the task is "delete duplicated record from BOTH TABLES accounting NULLs":

```sql
DELETE t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.x <=> t2.x
              AND t1.y <=> t2.y;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b6ae53eba890b90828b9a0a2b64e8837)

---

Assuming the task is "delete duplicated record from both tables NOT accounting NULLs":

```sql
DELETE t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 USING (x, y);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=610a8eceb6a01e7d8d608ad05d311d4e)

---

If the task is "delete duplicated record from one table and store them in another table" then edit `DELETE t1.*, t2.*` and store only those table which records must be deleted, for example, `DELETE t1.*`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is to remove duplicate from a table that exist in another table

if all colums have non null value then:-

```
DELETE t1 
FROM tbl_test_1 t1
INNER JOIN  tbl_test_2 t2
ON t1.col_1 = t2.col_1
AND t1.col_2 = t2.col_2
WHERE t2.id is  not null
```

Here if a particualr coulm from both table are NULL , we miss that.
So to catch colm match with NULL as well, try this:-

```
#to check before deletion
SELECT * , 
concat_ws("_",COALESCE(t1.col_1, 'null'),COALESCE(t1.col_2, 'null')),
concat_ws("_",COALESCE(t2.col_1,'null'),COALESCE(t2.col_2,'null')) 
FROM tbl_test_1  t1
left JOIN  tbl_test_2 t2
ON concat_ws("_",COALESCE(t1.col_1, 'null'),COALESCE(t1.col_2, 'null'))= concat_ws("_",COALESCE(t2.col_1, 'null'),COALESCE(t2.col_2, 'null'))

WHERE t2.id is  not null
```

delete query

```
#delete query
DELETE t1 
FROM tbl_test_1  t1
left JOIN  tbl_test_2 t2
ON concat_ws("_",COALESCE(t1.col_1, 'null'),COALESCE(t1.col2, 'null'))= concat_ws("_",COALESCE(t2.col_1, 'null'),COALESCE(t2.col2, 'null'))
WHERE t2.id is  not null
```